# What plant is this seed of?

Tags: identification, seeds

[image]

I live in NY Long island and of course it's fall season[image]

Comment: Could you post another picture with a ruler beside the seed so that we have a sense of scale, please? Also, some information about where the seed came from (found in a wooded area? found in your flower garden? found in your vegetable garden? given to you by a friend?) would be helpful.

Comment: In general, for seed and fruits (and other difficult to identify parts), it is better to have much more specimens.  Could you tell us where did you find it? On the garden? on a street? Which plants growth there? (possibly some plants still have few seeds)

Comment: I found it on the bathroom floor and am wondering how it got there. It's 5-7mm in diameter. I think I saw it just fall out of thin air with the corner of my eye! Definitely not a tomato seed. Added a close-up pic.

Answer (score 1):

Very difficult to give an ID based on a seed alone. <strike>However, based on the location and assuming it is from a native tree, I would suggest it is from the American Elm, *Ulmus americana*.</strike>

---

Edit:

Changed my mind, *Ulmus americana* has much larger wings on the samara.

Based on location and image, the closest fit I would suggest is *Betula nigra*, the River Birch:
[image] 
 [Image Source: https://projects.ncsu.edu/cals/plantbiology/ncsc/tnc/betula.htm](https://projects.ncsu.edu/cals/plantbiology/ncsc/tnc/betula.htm%20)

Comment: I think it's too small for an elm - also, most elms release their samara earlier in the year. To me, it looks more like a tomato seed with some dried flesh attached to it.

Comment: @Jurp disagree with tomato - too big, too flat, no hairs on the surface. Not convinced by the idea of dried flesh - it's unlikely to be floating about if that's the case.

Comment: I agree with you. I just said that it looked like a tomato, not that it was one. It also looks like a datura, too, but isn't one. Really difficult to ID a plant from seed unless the seed is more than a little unusual. Guess I should've been more specific in my comment. :)